# Ubuntu - Abnormal behavior on "screen" command

Tags: gnu-screen

I'm trying to send to the background "bitcoind".

```
$ screen bitcoind -daemon &
[1] 5289
```

Then I query for this process PID and the PID have changed

```
$ ps -ef | grep bitcoin
someuser     4003     1 14 16:16 ?        00:00:39 bitcoind -daemon
someuser     5384  3648  0 16:20 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto bitcoin
```

Then I do:

```
$ screen -r
There is no screen to be resumed.
```

I'm trying to get this "bitcoind" program to the background but for some reason the PID cahnges and I think this is the cause of screen not working. Can someone give me some clues on how to get this process to the background so when I exit the SSH sesion the bitcoind will continue to run?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04

Best Regards,

Answer (score 3):

I assume by `bitcoind` you mean this [`bitcoind`](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bitcoind).

Let's see what you are doing:

- You are starting a `screen` which usually will start the following program in it.
- As a program you pass `bitcoind -daemon`. This will start `bitcoind` in the background (usually by using [`fork(2)`](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=fork&apropos=0&sektion=2&manpath=Debian+7.0+wheezy&format=html&locale=en)).
- And you pass `&` to send the `screen` into background of your shell. The PID you see is the PID your shell started, the one of the `screen`.

As you passed `-daemon` to `bitcoind`, it has moved itself into background. As there is no more foreground process visible to `screen` it has terminated itself. Thus you do not see the 5289 PID at all and your `bitcoind` process has a PID you did not expect.

TL;DR: just call `bitcoind -daemon` and it should go in background.